# Windows Server 2012: how to prevent IIS from choosing SHA-1 for connections?

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012, hash, cryptography

**The problem:** IIS on Windows 2012 picks SHA-1 algorithm when the client uses SHA-1 certificate. Even though the server-side certificate is SHA-256. So Chrome/Edge don't work.

On analogous Windows 2016 setup: IIS uses a proper algorithm and everything works. This is because there was [KB4516061](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-24-2019-kb4516061-os-build-14393-3242-7c042be2-d992-c58e-65e1-4ffdf3a6ff2c) which fixed the issue: *Addresses an issue that chooses a SHA-1 hash algorithm for the secure (HTTPS/TLS) connection to a Windows server.*

(Yes, I know about SHA-1, but this is a corpo environment, and some users still have SHA-1 certificates on their smart cards...)

**Question:** how to make it work on Windows 2012? Maybe some registry setting? Some hotfix KB I am not aware of?

What I tried:

1. "Best practices" in IIS Crypto.
2. That, and in addition disable SSL3.0 and SHA-1 in all lists.
3. `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010003` - remove SHA-1 from `Functions` value, but that messes up the whole computer.

Answer (score 1):

A way to overcome this is to:

1. Disable everything except TLS 1.0 in *server* protocols in IISCrypto. Don't touch client protocols.
2. Since Edge doesn't allow TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 by default, apply the following which will stop working in version 91 in a few months.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"SSLVersionMin"="tls1"
```

Another option would be to force the website in IE11 compatibility mode in Edge, IE11 is much less picky.